# Can you make a Django form dropdown box accept a model as its choices?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a real estate site where I am trying to be able to upload multiple photos to one `'property'` without going through the `Django admin panel` (so I can multi-select photos.)

**The current view for custom-built form**

[image: current view for custom-built form]

I am able to choose multiple files, upload them to my `'uploads'` folder, and able to see them in the admin panel for databases. The issue is that the property name from the form I built doesn't connect the `Property object` to the `Property Photos objects`. It's just a `null` value.

When I click on a `Property Photo object` only then does it assign the `Property object` to it?

**Property Photo objects BEFORE**

[image: Property Photo objects BEFORE]

**Property Photo object Once I click on it and push save**

[image: Property Photo object Once I click on it and push save]

**Property Photo object After**

[image: Property Photo object After]

### How do I get to be able to select (using a dropdown) a Property object from all my Property objects as a list and assign those photos uploaded to that Property object?

---

Below are my: `HTML form`, `models.py`, `views.py`, and `forms.py`

- photo_upload.html

```
<body>
    <form action=""
          method="POST"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="fs-1">Photo Upload</div>
      {{ image_form }}
      <button>Upload</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

- models.py

```
class Property(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Properties'

    address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, )

    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    listing_status = models.ForeignKey(ListingStatus,
                                       on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                       null=True,
                                       blank=True,
                                       related_name='property')

    css_file = models.ForeignKey(CssFile,
                                 on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                 null=True,
                                 related_name='property')

    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent,
                              on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                              null=True,
                              related_name='property')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address


class PropPhoto(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Property Photos'

    property_name = models.ForeignKey(Property,
                                      on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                      null=True,
                                      default='',
                                      related_name='property')
    prop_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='property_photos',
                                   default='', )
```

- views.py

```
def images_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        image_form = ImageUploadsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if image_form.is_valid():
            images = request.FILES.getlist('prop_photo')
            for img in images:
                photo = PropPhoto.objects.create(prop_photo=img,)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks/')
    else:
        image_form = ImageUploadsForm()

    return render(request, 'personal_property_site/photo_upload.html', {
        'image_form': image_form,
    })
```

- forms.py

```
address_list = []
for prop in Property.objects.all():
    address_list.insert(1, (prop.slug, prop.slug))
address_list.reverse()

class ImageUploadsForm(forms.Form):
    property_name = forms.CharField(label='Property Name',
                                    required=True,
                                    max_length=250,
                                    widget=forms.Select(
                                        attrs={
                                            'class': 'form-control',
                                        },
                                        choices=address_list, #this is what to change
                                    ))

    prop_photo = forms.FileField(label='Upload property photos',
                                 required=True,
                                 widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(
                                     attrs={
                                         'class': 'form-control',
                                         'multiple': True,
                                     },
                                 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line, you have to assign the property to it

```
photo = PropPhoto.objects.create(prop_photo=img,)
```

First, get the property you want to assign to the photo

```
property = Property.objects.get(-insert whatever here to identify property-)
```

Then:

```
photo = PropPhoto.objects.create(prop_photo=img,property_name = property)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought I had done something like that but I couldn't get it to work.

My views.py after the change:
images = request.FILES.getlist('prop_photo')
            prop_name = Property.objects.get()
            for img in images:
                photo = PropPhoto.objects.create(prop_photo=img, property_name=prop_name)